# android contentprovider pre process text

Tags: android, sqlite

i am using Android ContentProviders to access my android application's sqlite database.
some of the text held on the database requires that i call

```
public static Spanned fromHtml (String source)
```

once i have retrieved it from the database. this is because the store text contains

```
& apos;
```

etc, escaped content.

how can i process the retrieved text before displaying it in my ListFragment activity.?

Do i have to create a custom cursor adapter for this?

or are there other options open to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you have other options

1. store it html-decoded (you didn't say how the sql database was populated)
2. create an DAO from the database, and let the DAO implement the escape method